# How to disable loading of images from browser

Tags: browser

I am using multiple browsers (IE,Firefox and Safari).

I am not interested in viewing the images due to low internet speed. Can i block the images and view only the content that i am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better look into [this](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acpv.html) article to start the browser in  “text mode”.